# shared_ptr with = symbol not allowed

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Why does the below code compile

```
shared_ptr<parent> p(new parent);
```

while the below one doesn't

```
shared_ptr<parent> p2 = new parent;
```

Is there any reason for not allowing '=' symbol for shared_ptr?

Generally, if a pointer like

```
int *p = new int;
```

should be same as  that of

```
int *p(new int);
```

isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing unique\_ptr and friends operator= overload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916931/missing-unique-ptr-and-friends-operator-overload)

Answer (score 4):

`std::shared_ptr`'s "pointer receiving" constructor is declared [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

```
template< class Y >
explicit shared_ptr( Y* ptr );
```

With that, you can't use copy initialization (`shared_ptr<parent> p2 = new parent;`).

The best reason that I can think why `std::shared_ptr`'s constructor is made `explicit` is that you would less likely to make mistakes passing a raw, unmanaged by `std::shared_ptr` object, to a function receiving a `std::shared_ptr`.

```
#include <memory>


void func(std::shared_ptr<int> ptr) { /* ... */}

int main() {
    auto iptr = std::make_shared<int>();
    func(iptr);  // OK
    
    /*
    int* iptr = new int;
    func(iptr);  // Unclear who would eventually manage (delete) the pointer
    // ...
    delete iptr; // Undefined behavior!
    */
}
```

If the constructor wasn't made `explicit`, then you could do the commented-out code.

Also, as what @R. Martinho Fernandes has [suggested](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11311914#11311914), you can have a problem if non-`new`ed pointers are being passed.

```
int myint;
int* iptr = &myint;
func(iptr);  // iptr doesn't point to a newed (dynamically-allocated) object
             //   std::shared_ptr, by default, uses delete on its managed pointer
             //   if there are no more references to that pointer
```

Still you could do it wrong if you aren't careful when you're using two separate `std::shared_ptr`s to manage a raw pointer.

```
int* riptr = new int;
std::shared_ptr<int> iptr(riptr);
std::shared_ptr<int> iptr2(riptr); // WRONG!
```

With your questions about raw pointers, the two are essentially the same, but that isn't necessarily applicable to `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Mark Garcia: Thank you for the answer. I knew about explicit constructor. But, I want to know why is it made explicit?? Is there any reason for it?

Comment: @Saran wrong question. As a rule of thumb for API design, when you have a one-argument constructor, start with explicit and find reasons to make it implicit, not the other way around. Implicit conversions cause problems often and do so silently on top.

Answer (score 3):

Because the constructor taking a pointer as single argument is **explicit**, you can’t use the
assignment notation here because that is considered to be an **`implicit conversion`**.

You can also use the convenience function make_shared() here:

```
std::shared_ptr<parent> p2 = std::make_shared<parent>();
```

This way of creation is faster and safer because it uses `one` instead of `two allocations`: one for the object and one for the shared data the shared pointer uses to control the object.